# Error - is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @74b715ff)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I have this problem, and want to solve it by NetBeans, I still don't know how to use maven from the prompt, I found a solution but it is from the prompt, does anyone know how? Thanks!

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12 cannot be cast to class br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.FuncionarioResp (java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12 is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.FuncionarioResp is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @35b254b3)

## Complete Error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-04-05 21:31:38.175 ERROR 15452 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.ProjetoEstoqueApplication.main(ProjetoEstoqueApplication.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12 cannot be cast to class br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.FuncionarioResp (java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12 is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.FuncionarioResp is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @74b715ff)
    at br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.ProjetoEstoqueApplication.run(ProjetoEstoqueApplication.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2021-04-05 21:31:38.204  INFO 15452 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-05 21:31:38.204  INFO 15452 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-05 21:31:38.204  INFO 15452 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-04-05 21:31:38.219  INFO 15452 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  12.710 s
Finished at: 2021-04-05T21:31:39-03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Class FuncionarioResp

```
package br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class FuncionarioResp extends Funcionario{
    
    @Column(length = 10,nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Usuário obrigatório.")
    @Length(max = 10,message = "Usuário deve ter no máximo 10 caracteres.")
    private String usuario;
    @Column(length = 6,nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Senha obrigatória.")
    @Length(max = 6, min = 6, message ="A senha deve conter 6 caracteres.")
    private String senha;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "funcionarioresp")
    @Valid
    private List<Entrada> entradas = new ArrayList<>();
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "funcionarioresp")
    @Valid
    private List<Despache> despaches = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }



   public List<Entrada> getEntradas() {
        return entradas;
    }

    public void setEntradas(List<Entrada> entradas) {
        this.entradas = entradas;
    }

    public List<Despache> getDespaches() {
        return despaches;
    }

    public void setDespaches(List<Despache> despaches) {
        this.despaches = despaches;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }


    public FuncionarioResp() {
    }

    
}
```

## Entrada Repository

**The error appeared when adding this repository.**

```
package br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.repository;
import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.Entrada;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EntradaRepository extends JpaRepository<Entrada, Long>{
    
    public List<Entrada> findByFuncionariorespId(Long funcionariorespId, Pageable page);
  

}
```

## Application

```
package br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque;

//import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.Alocacao;
import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.Entrada;
import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.FuncionarioAdm;
import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.FuncionarioResp;
import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.model.Produto;
import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.repository.EntradaRepository;
import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.repository.FuncionarioAdmRepository;
import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.repository.FuncionarioRespRepository;
import br.edu.iff.projetoEstoque.repository.ProdutoRepository;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjetoEstoqueApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    private FuncionarioRespRepository funcionarioRespRepo;
    @Autowired
    private FuncionarioAdmRepository funcionarioAdmRepo;
    @Autowired
    private ProdutoRepository produtoRepo;
     @Autowired
    private EntradaRepository entradaRepo;
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjetoEstoqueApplication.class, args);
    }
        
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception{
            
            
            //FuncionarioResp
            
            FuncionarioResp fr1 = new FuncionarioResp();
            fr1.setNome("Ana");
            fr1.setCpf("368.428.700-89");
            fr1.setEmail("anacasdr@gmail.com");
            fr1.setUsuario("anaca");
            fr1.setSenha("060320");
            funcionarioRespRepo.save(fr1);
            
            //fr1.setDespaches();
            
            //FuncionarioAdm
            
            FuncionarioAdm fa1 = new FuncionarioAdm();
            fa1.setNome("Hiwri");
            fa1.setCpf("856.280.040-65");
            fa1.setEmail("hiwri@gmail.com");
            fa1.setUsuario("hiwri");
            fa1.setSenha("330260");
            fa1.setChave("2563569635");
            
            funcionarioAdmRepo.save(fa1);
            
            //Produto
        
            Produto p1 = new Produto();

            p1.setNome("Geladeira");
            p1.setCategoria("Eletrodomestico");
            p1.setPeso((int) 10.00);
            
            produtoRepo.save(p1);
            
             Entrada e1 = new Entrada();
        
            e1.setFuncionarioresp((FuncionarioResp) List.of(fr1));
            e1.setProduto((Produto) List.of(p1));
           // e1.setAlocacao((Alocacao) List.of(a1));
        
            e1.setDataHoraEntrada(Calendar.getInstance());
            
            
            entradaRepo.save(e1);
            
        }

}
```

## Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.edu.iff</groupId>
    <artifactId>projetoEstoque</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projetoEstoque</name>
    <description>Projeto para a disciplina de programação para WEB.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can disable spring boot devtools autorestart. But you need to disable the restart loader, so you need to apply the following property before you call SpringApplication.run. Your main method should look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Additionally, if you have no need for devtools simply remove the dependency (*spring-boot-devtools*).

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.restart.disable
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.restart.limitations

Answer (score 0):

In case with Kafka, I saw the same issue in this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/UJesCn731G4?t=2565).

The problem was that the `key-deserializer` and `value-deserializer` were misconfigured.