# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException for same class objects, How to solve this?

Tags: java

I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException for the objects of same class. This is the code that causes the error.

```
try (Session session = configDatabaseService.getSessionFactory().openSession())
        {
            List list = session.createQuery("FROM SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity detail WHERE detail.dateAdded>:dateAdded").setParameter("dateAdded", Instant.ofEpochMilli(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (2 * 24 * 3600 * 1000L)).getTime())).list();

            for (Object spareLabsPollStatusDetail : list)
            {
                Optional<DimResident> dimResident = this.dimResidentRepository.findById(Math.toIntExact(((SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity) (spareLabsPollStatusDetail)).getDimResidentId()));

                if (dimResident.isPresent())
                {
                     //deleted code for brevity
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("NOT Updated dimResident SpareLabsKey  = [" + dimResident.get().getResidentID() + "]");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.print(e);
            if (Logger.isErrorEnabled())
                Logger.error(e);
        }
```

This is the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.rossmoor.sparelabs.model.entities.SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity cannot be cast to class com.rossmoor.sparelabs.model.entities.SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity (com.rossmoor.sparelabs.model.entities.SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.rossmoor.sparelabs.model.entities.SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @86fbeb3)2022-09-25 18:31:56,588 WARN  [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$HouseKeeper: HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=55s727ms524µs300ns).
    2022-09-25 18:31:57:310 [ERROR] [restartedMain:ID=22]:[SpareLabsClientServiceImpl.java:834] java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.rossmoor.sparelabs.model.entities.SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity cannot be cast to class com.rossmoor.sparelabs.model.entities.SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity (com.rossmoor.sparelabs.model.entities.SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.rossmoor.sparelabs.model.entities.SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @86fbeb3)
        at com.rossmoor.sparelabs.services.web.SpareLabsClientServiceImpl.updateSpareLabsKeysInDimResidentTable(SpareLabsClientServiceImpl.java:794)
        at com.rossmoor.sparelabs.services.web.SpareLabsClientServiceImpl.doDataSynchronization(SpareLabsClientServiceImpl.java:574)
        at com.rossmoor.sparelabs.SpareLabsApplication.run(SpareLabsApplication.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at com.rossmoor.sparelabs.SpareLabsApplication.main(SpareLabsApplication.java:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

What does this error mean? How to solve this?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [ClassCastException casting a class instance to its own class because it is in an "unnamed module" with gradel and tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71959645/). You seem to have the same class *twice* in the classpath.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The class is defined only once, it is not from libraries.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961552/error-is-in-unnamed-module-of-loader-org-springframework-boot-devtools-restart

Comment: "com...SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com...SparelabsPollStatusDetailEntity is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @86fbeb3" - 2 classes with the same name are loaded by 2 different class loaders. Simple as that. For the why? No idea.

Comment: @tgdavies Your suggestion worked.